# create active pages with an editable text panel and attachments using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to create active web pages using node.js. The pages are to have some tabs, and every tab has a list of items. As one item clicked, an editable panel will appear. User can tip text in the panel and save the typed content. It would be also very nice, if any documents can to be attached to an item. The layout of the page is skizzed as below:

```
+----------------------------------+
|  Tab1  |//Tab2//|  Tab3  |       |
+----------------------------------+
+---------+ Tab2-Item2:            |
|Item1    | +--------------------+ |
+---------+ |Editable Text Panel | |
|//Item2//| |...                 | |
+---------+ +--------------------+ |
|Item3    | [Save] [Load] [Attach] |
+---------+ -----------------------+
```

I have come across two candidates ejs and jade which can seemingly accomplish the job. However I'm not sure which one is actually better for this task. Are there any recommended nodejs examples addressing such topics?

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to start with some HTML tutorial/general web development tutorial first since what you're asking for is actually quite broad and involves the knowledge of several different components.

Comment: @fstanis could you recommend any html templates or examples which could fullfill my task?

Comment: [Bootstrap examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) might be a good place to start, but you might want to check out a [course](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web) regarding HTML and CSS first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with Node.js **however** bear in mind that Node.js is a *Back-end framework* while your requirements seem to be more related to a *Front-end framework*.

Therefore what you need a combination of both, you can choose [(Node.js **OR** an Apache server) **AND** (jQueryUI **OR** Bootstrap **OR** Foundation)]

The first is the *Back-end*, I recommend you to use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). The second requirement is the *Front-end*, I recommend you to start with **Foundation**, take a look at the [Accordion component](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html), the [Tabs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html#tabs-deeplink-1), the [Forms](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html), and maybe the [Dropdown](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html) too. There you can find snippets that you can copy paste in this [Foundation JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBSA4/) to see them in action. For example to add a Tabs component you would write

```
<h3 id="tabs" data-magellan-destination="tabs">Tabs</h3>
<dl class="tabs">
  <dd class="active"><a href="#simple1">Simple Tab 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">Simple Tab 2</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple3">Simple Tab 3</a></dd>
</dl>
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li class="active" id="simple1Tab">This is simple tab 1's content. Pretty neat, huh?</li>
  <li id="simple2Tab">This is simple tab 2's content. Now you see it!</li>
  <li id="simple3Tab">This is simple tab 3's content. It's, you know...okay.</li>
</ul>
```

On the HTML section.

If you decide to use **jQueryUI** take a look at the [Toggle](https://jqueryui.com/toggle/), the [Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) and the [Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/). There you can find snippets that you can test on this [jQueryUI JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/queryj/CnEUh/1/). For example to add some Tabs you would write

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On the HTML section. Don't forget there is also some JavaScript involved.

If you decide to use **Bootstrap** take a look at [Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#form). There you can find snippets that you can test on this [Bootstrap JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/). For example to add a Button you can write

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a>
```

On the HTML section.

Comment: thanks alot for your comprehensive answers. How could the added text be saved on the server? Any hint would be appreciated.